# How to determine an object's class?

Tags: java, inheritance

If class `B` and class `C` extend class `A` and I have an object of type `B` or `C`, how can I determine of which type it is an instance?

Comment: @starblue Casting would be the first thing that comes to mind. I doubt the *instanceof* operator would exist if there wasn't any need for it.

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy wouldn't it be good to use the isntanceof operator first. If there's a cast to an incompatible type, I believe that will result in a ClassCastException

Answer (score 909, accepted):

```
if (obj instanceof C) {
//your code
}
```

Comment: It is useful to note the reverse check or how to check if an Object is NOT an instance of a class: `if(!(obj instanceof C))`

Comment: I believe getClass() method is the answer to the original question. In this case (obj instanceof A) would also give "true" output but the intent is to find the runtime class of the object in picture. If Parent1 is extended by Child1 and Child2, try the following `code`  Child1 child1 = new Child1();
Parent1 parentChild = new Child2();
Child2 child2 = new Child2();
(child1 instanceof Parent1);
(child1 instanceof Child1);
(parentChild instanceof Child2);
(parentChild instanceof Parent1);
(parentChild instanceof Child1); `code`  , it may clear the intent of instanceof.

Comment: Definitely an alternative to building an interface

Comment: What if I have two classes implementing single interface? How do I distinct exact class of the object?

Comment: One thing though, it does not work if obj is null. The solution would then be ParentInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(Child.class)

Comment: Imagine case where you have B, C, D, E, etc. Solution becomes very verbose. [Pattern matching](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html) is much better but is [still in proposal state](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/305).

Comment: Since i cannot offer an improved answer: Since JAVA 14 there is the concept of patternmatching for instance of https://openjdk.org/jeps/305. Just append a variable name like `if (obj instanceof C cVariable)` this allows you to use cVariable without casting it to C.

Answer (score 443):

Use [`Object.getClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()).  It returns the runtime type of the object. Here's how to call it using your example:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}

class Main {  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    C c = new C();
    Class clazz = c.getClass();
    System.out.println(clazz); 
  } 
}
```

Output:

```
class C
```

You can also compare two `Class` instances to see if two objects are the same type.

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}

class Main {  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    B b = new B();
    Class c1 = b.getClass();
    C c = new C();
    Class c2 = c.getClass();
    System.out.println(c1 == c2); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: This is actually how you determine an object's class

Comment: flawless answer @Bill

Comment: Not sure why this is not the most popular answer

Comment: An example is 99% of the good answer

Answer (score 201):

Multiple right answers were presented, but there are still more methods: `Class.isAssignableFrom()` and simply attempting to cast the object (which might throw a `ClassCastException`).

### Possible ways summarized

Let's summarize the possible ways to test if an object `obj` is an instance of type `C`:

```
// Method #1
if (obj instanceof C)
    ;

// Method #2
if (C.class.isInstance(obj))
    ;

// Method #3
if (C.class.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass()))
    ;

// Method #4
try {
    C c = (C) obj;
    // No exception: obj is of type C or IT MIGHT BE NULL!
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
}

// Method #5
try {
    C c = C.class.cast(obj);
    // No exception: obj is of type C or IT MIGHT BE NULL!
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
}
```

### Differences in `null` handling

There is a difference in `null` handling though:

- In the first 2 methods expressions evaluate to `false` if `obj` is `null` (`null` is not instance of anything).
- The 3rd method would throw a `NullPointerException` obviously.
- The 4th and 5th methods on the contrary accept `null` because `null` can be cast to any type!

> To remember: `null` **is not** an instance of any type but it **can be cast** to any type.

### Notes

- `Class.getName()` should not be used to perform an *"is-instance-of"* test becase if the object is not of type `C` but a subclass of it, it may have a completely different name and package (therefore class names will obviously not match) but it is still of type `C`.
- For the same inheritance reason `Class.isAssignableFrom()` is not *symmetric*:
  `obj.getClass().isAssignableFrom(C.class)` would return `false` if the type of `obj` is a subclass of `C`.

Comment: This is a really great summary of many of the pitfalls in the different methods. Thanks for such a complete write up!

Answer (score 37):

You can use:

```
Object instance = new SomeClass();
instance.getClass().getName(); //will return the name (as String) (== "SomeClass")
instance.getClass(); //will return the SomeClass' Class object
```

HTH. But I think most of the time it is no good practice to use that for control flow or something similar...

Comment: I used it to create generic logger, So i sent object to the logger, and it logs depending on the class name of the object, rather than giving log tag or log string everytime. thank you

Answer (score 22):

Any use of any of the methods suggested is considered a code smell which is based in a bad OO design.

If your design is good, you should not find yourself needing to use `getClass()` or `instanceof`.

Any of the suggested methods will do, but just something to keep in mind, design-wise.

Comment: Yeah, probably 99% of the uses of getClass and instanceof can be avoided with polymorphic method calls.

Comment: i am in agreement.
in this case i'm working with objects generated from xml following a poorly designed schema which i do not have ownership of.

Comment: That's generally the case in these situations, legacy code, bad design not in your ownership, etc...

Comment: Not nessecarily.  Sometimes separation of interfaces is good.  There are times when you want to know if A is a B, but you don't want to make it mandatory that A is a B, as only A is required for most functionality - B has optional functionality.

Comment: Also, there are times when you need to ensure that the object is of the same class you're comparing with; for instance I like to override Object's equals method when I create my own class.  I always verify the object coming in is of the same class.

Comment: Also, I would say telling people something is bad without explaining exactly why or giving a reference to a paper, book, or any other resource where the issue is explained is considered not constructive. Therefore and knowing that I am in StackOverflow, I don't know why people have upvoted this answer so much. Something is changing here...

Comment: some tasks like serializing, getting type maybe the simplest way?

Comment: There are other cases especially hen discussing DI or producer frameworks where knowing the class types is necessary for binding.

Comment: I agree with @AdriánPérez Cuz In my case, using getClass for an object saved my API from overhead of giving the name by hand everytime developer initializes the API class. Here to be OO and save the redundant repetition of code, i needed to use `object.getClass().getSimpleName()` , this is one case, i think there are many more where developer needs instanceof to make function generic and follow OO principles...

Comment: In theory there's no difference between theory and practice; in practice there is (Snepscheut).  OO theory is fine, but when confronted with the real world things get ugly.

Comment: I know I'm a bit late here, but I see your point on how it shouldn't be necessary, though recently I had run into a situation that actually needed it, and that situation was in the override of Object's equals method. I needed to create a special case within HashMap that agreed with equality, but the usual equals method did not work. There may have been a better method for doing so, but the instanceof function really helped

Comment: I can't agree with you.  If you want to override an equals function: `@Override public boolean equals(Object obj){}`, you must check the class type. Activity, it is a bad OO design if you **don't use getClass()/instanceof**.

Answer (score 16):

We can use reflection in this case

```
objectName.getClass().getName();
```

Example:-

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String name = request.getClass().getName();
}
```

In this case you will get name of the class which object pass to `HttpServletRequest` interface refference variable.

Comment: this is correct. using only `obj.getClass()` will return the className, prefixex by the word `class`

Comment: `request.getClass().getName();` prints all package ! along with class name

Answer (score 13):

There is also an [`.isInstance`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)) method on the "`Class`" class. if you get an object's class via `myBanana.getClass()` you can see if your object `myApple` is an instance of the same class as `myBanana` via

```
myBanana.getClass().isInstance(myApple)
```

Answer (score 3):

checking with `isinstance()` would not be enough if you want to know in run time. 
use:

```
if(someObject.getClass().equals(C.class){
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I Used Java 8 generics to get what is the object instance at runtime rather than having to use switch case

```
 public <T> void print(T data) {
    System.out.println(data.getClass().getName()+" => The data is " + data);
}
```

pass any type of data and the method will print the type of data you passed while calling it. eg

```
    String str = "Hello World";
    int number = 10;
    double decimal = 10.0;
    float f = 10F;
    long l = 10L;
    List list = new ArrayList();
    print(str);
    print(number);
    print(decimal);
    print(f);
    print(l);
    print(list);
```

Following is the output

```
java.lang.String => The data is Hello World
java.lang.Integer => The data is 10
java.lang.Double => The data is 10.0
java.lang.Float => The data is 10.0
java.lang.Long => The data is 10
java.util.ArrayList => The data is []
```

Comment: Using generics here, adds no value. Change the method declaration to `public void print(Object data)` and it will still work exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **getSimpleName()**.

Let's say we have a object: **Dog d = new Dog()**,

The we can use below statement to get the class name: Dog. E.g.:

**d.getClass().getSimpleName();** // return String 'Dog'.

PS: d.getClass() will give you the full name of your object.

Answer (score 1):

`your_instance.getClass().getSimpleName()` will gives type name for example: String, Integer, Double, Boolean...

Answer (score 0):

I use the blow function in my GeneralUtils class, check it may be useful

```
    public String getFieldType(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        return "Unable to identify the class name";
    }
    return o.getClass().getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `instanceof` `operator` to find weather a **object** is of particular `class` or not.

```
booleanValue = (object instanceof class)
```

> JDK 14 extends the instanceof operator: you can specify a binding
> variable; if the result of the instanceof operator is true, then the
> object being tested is assigned to the binding variable.

please visit official Java [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/pattern-matching-instanceof-operator.html) for more reference.

### Sample program to illustrate usage of `instanceof` `operator` :

```
import java.util.*;

class Foo{
    @Override 
    public String toString(){
        return "Bar";
    }
}

class Bar{
    public Object reference;
    @Override 
    public String toString(){
        return "Foo";
    }
}
public class InstanceofUsage{
    public static void main(final String ... $){
        final List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

        var out = System.out;

        list.add(new String("Foo Loves Bar"));
        list.add(33.3);
        list.add(404_404);
        list.add(new Foo());
        list.add(new Bar());

        for(final var o : list){
            if(o instanceof Bar b && b.reference == null){
                out.println("Bar : Null");
            }   
            if(o instanceof String s){
                out.println("String : "+s);
            }

            if(o instanceof Foo f){
                out.println("Foo : "+f);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

### output:

```
$ javac InstanceofUsage.java && java InstanceofUsage 
String : Foo Loves Bar
Foo : Bar
Bar : Null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Superclass {
 // Superclass implementation
}

class Subclass extends Superclass {
 // Subclass implementation
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Superclass obj = new Superclass();

    // Check if the object is an instance of the superclass
    if (obj instanceof Superclass) {
        System.out.println("Object is an instance of Superclass");
    }

    // Check if the object is an instance of the subclass
    if (obj instanceof Subclass) {
        System.out.println("Object is an instance of Subclass");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Object is not an instance of Subclass");
    }
  }
 }
```