# Java method: retrieve the inheriting type

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I have several classes that extend C and I would need a method that accepts any argument of type C. But in this method I would like to know if I'm dealing with A or B.

*

```
public A extends C
public B extends C

public void goForIt(C c)()
```

If I cast how can I retrieve the type in a clean way (I just read using getClass or instanceof [is often not the best way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541749/how-to-determine-an-objects-class-in-java/541788#541788)).

**Sorry but [I can't type closing braces](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19330/problem-with-the-closing-brace)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clean way is *not* to "retrieve the type" explicitly at any point.

Instead, you make `goForIt()` a method of class `C` and have `A` and `B` override it and implement it differently, possibly calling `super.goForIt()` in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `instanceof` isn't very clean. Sounds like `goForIt()` should change behavior depending on some property of the subclass. Instead of hard-coding the question to be "is it an A?", make the question "does the class have some key property Foo?" (which A has, presumably). And then, make the classes answer the question.

```
public class C {
  public abstract boolean isFoo();
  public void goForIt(C c) {
    if (isFoo()) {
      ...
  }
  ...
}

public class A extends C {
  public boolean isFoo() {
    return true;
  }
  ...
}

public class B extends C {
  public boolean isFoo() {
    return false;
  }
  ...
}
```