# How does one determine if an EventObject is a MouseEvent an ActionEvent or something else?

Tags: java, mouseevent, actionevent

How does one determine if an `EventObject` is a `MouseEvent` an `ActionEvent` or something else?

Is there a simple way to check the type of an `EventObject`?

Comment: How did you reach a situation where you need to check the type of event? If you provided some background to your question, it will probably become apparent where you should have cast the event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine an object's class (in Java)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541749/how-to-determine-an-objects-class-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the instanceof keyword.

```
public boolean isActionEvent(EventObject o){
   return o instanceof ActionEvent;
}
```

More info here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `instanceof` operator.

```
objectname instanceof EventObjectName
```