# How to check a varible is String type or not in java

Tags: java

I have a configuration file from where some values are coming ,in the file the data are present along with their types.I have to check the data which are coming from the configuration file is a String type or not.How can i do that..Here is my code

```
    for (String tagName : record.getAllTags().keySet()) {
        com.etl.core.model.fmtg.Tag t = record.getAllTags().get(tagName);

        md.put(t.getName().trim(), "");
    }
```

t.getName() is the name of the variables which are coming though the file and if i do t.getType() i will get the name of the type ... so how i can check the t.getName() is a String type or not

Comment: Yep, `if (myString instanceof String) ...`.

Comment: Agree with Salah, instanceof is enough for you. if( t.getName() instanceof String){...}

Comment: What do `getType()` and `getName()` return? Is `GetType()` a string representation of the type of your variable? If so: please clarify this. It would mean `instanceof` is not appropriate.

Comment: If t.getName() returns name of the type as string like "String" or "int" you can just check t.getName().equals("String") its enogh.

Comment: What does "a String type" mean? Must it be exactly the `String` class, would similar classes be ok like `StringBuilder` or even everything that has a `toString()` implemented?

Comment: @zapl its String class

Comment: if((t.getName() instanceof String)){
   
    System.out.println(t.getName());
  } not working

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - Consult the JDK spec for info.  There is no `getType` for an Object instance (dunno about the Tag class), but `getClass` returns a reference to the object's Class instance, and `getName` on the Class instance returns the class name as a String.  If one wants to check whether there is a String or StringBuilder or some other "string-like" class, one could do `instanceof CharSequence`.

Comment: @HotLicks: I'm aware of that, which is why I was asking what `com.etl.core.model.fmtg.Tag#getType()` returns. "**if i do `t.getType()` i will get the name of the type**"

Comment: Yeah, no clue what that class may do.  etl.com routes to intertek.com, apparently a product testing/certification company.  No hint of an API with that package name.  Unless the OP reveals more then there's no more that can be done.

Answer (score 2):

To check the any `object` type in java use:

```
if (obj instanceof C) {
    //your code
}
```

For more [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541749/how-to-determine-an-objects-class-in-java).