# How do I get the type of an object's variable if I know the name of the variable in java?

Tags: java

Following is a class:

```
class Test{
    int x;
}
```

Now let's say I make an object of the class:

```
Test testObj = new Test();
```

Also, I have a String variable, which has the same value as the class variable:

```
String var = "x";
```

Now from this object `testObj` is there a way, that if I supply the name of the variable through the string `var`, and get the data type of variable x?

Comment: You can through reflection, but maybe there is a better way of doing it. What is the use case?

Comment: you can use, getClass method, but its can be used on objects, and not on values,

Comment: Agree with @engineercoding, this looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you're asking about a particular solution, but you are not explaining why you actually want to do this, and probably this particular solution is not the best way to solve the actual problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine an object's class (in Java)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541749/how-to-determine-an-objects-class-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Use [Class.getDeclaredField()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField%28java.lang.String%29):

```
Field field = testObj.getClass().getDeclaredField(var);
Class<?> typeOfField = field.getType();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using reflection:

```
String type = testObj.getClass().getDeclaredField(var).getType().getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection you might do

```
Class  aClass = MyObject.class
Field field = aClass.getField("someField");

MyObject objectInstance = new MyObject();

Object value = field.get(objectInstance);

field.set(objetInstance, value);
```

Comment: getField() only returns **public** fields.