# Java: get name of subclass from instance of superclass

Tags: java, class, extends

I have a class `public class N` and an object `A a = new B();`

The class B looks like this:

```
public class B extends A { ... }
```

I want to get a subclass name of the object *a* inside *N* as a String (also: *"B"*). How can i do this?

**EDIT:** In my case I use Visitor-Pattern. I have public void visit(A a), when a is previously defined as A a = new B(). Then I need to call public void visit(B b). How can I define, that I need to call exactly visit(B b)?

Comment: Where is N, in the  question?

Comment: Some class in which I define the object A

Comment: If you have `A a= new B()` are you asking how do you know that you actually have a `B`? Why do you need it as a string?

Comment: I edited the post. My object is: A a = new B();

Comment: Why do you want to get the subclass name? This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: @Dukeling I need to understand what action to take on an object, depending on its type

Comment: That's not the object-oriented way of doing things.

Comment: In my case I use Visitor-Pattern. I have public void visit(A a), when a is previously defined as A a = new B(). Then I need to call public void visit(B b). How can I define, that I need to call exactly visit(B b)?

Comment: So... [How to determine an object's class (in Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/541749), although it still sounds like you have a problem with your design.

Answer (score 3):

`a.getClass().getSimpleName()` should give exactly what you are asking for. It returns the name of the actual class of the object. For the full name (with package included), use `getClass().getName()`.

Comment: No. This method gives me "A" as output, but I want to get "B".

Comment: @cricket_007 It will, `A` does not refer to `class A` but to `Object A = new B()`. This would have been much clearer, if the naming conventions were followed.

Comment: is this a situation where you are going to have a list of case statements based on the type, because i wouldn't recommend that approach.   Add an enumeration instead, or even further a factory pattern would be better.