# How to determine a variable type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

I have this logic,

```
.switchMap((data: ISearchModalPayload | number ) => {..... }
```

where `data` is either an interface object or a number.

How can I determine the data type before I carry on with my routine?

I tried the following, from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/541769/2157801), but none worked:

- `if (obj instanceof C) {}`
- `Object.getClass()`
- `.isInstance`

Comment: `I tried the following`  - can you show exactly how you tried, because clearly, you don't have a class `C` in your code

Comment: `if (typeof data === "number") {  /* do number things */ } else { /* do object things */ }`?

Comment: [how to determine variable type in javascript](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+determine+variable+type+in+javascript&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS688US688&oq=how+to+determine+a+variable+type+in+jav&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2.9624j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @Xufox , it’s typescript , I apologize

Comment: Okay, please learn the difference between Java, JavaScript and TypeScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (typeof obj === 'number') {
  // do stuff
} else if (typeof obj === 'object') {
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator? E.g.

```
typeof obj === "number"
```