# How to print specific item from ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am trying to print specific item from my ArrayList

I have super class named  Item, I created a new class with ArrayList named db in the database I'm storing Cars,Bikes ,

```
ArrayList< Item > db = new ArrayList< Item >();

Car newCar = new Car(getModel(),getPrice());

db.add(newCar);

Bike newBike = new Bike(getModel(),getPrice())

db.add(newBike);
```

Now I'm trying to print only cars something like this,

```
if( db==newCar){
  System.out.println("The first car is : "+db.car)
}
else{

  System.out.println("The first bike is : "+db.car)

}
```

Comment: You would have found the solution while searching. many posts. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541749/how-to-determine-an-objects-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `instanceof` to check the *runtime* type of object.

Example of iteration:

```
for (Item item : db) {
    if (item instanceof Car){
        System.out.println("A car is: " + item)
    } else {
        System.out.println("A bike is: " + item)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, its exactly what I was looking for !