# Used entityManager in command dispatch interceptors

Tags: java, axon

I'm using Axon 4.3 with JPA/Spring.
I want to inject entityManager in my interceptor, so i used ContainerManagedEntityManagerProvider in my configuration. but i have this error when i run my application

> Description: Parameter 0 of method configureCommandBus in AxonConfig
> required a bean of type
> 'org.axonframework.springboot.util.jpa.ContainerManagedEntityManagerProvider'
> that could not be found.
>
> Action: Consider defining a bean of type
> 'org.axonframework.springboot.util.jpa.ContainerManagedEntityManagerProvider'
> in your configuration.

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(AxonAutoConfiguration.class)
public class AxonConfig {

    @Bean
    public CommandBus configureCommandBus(org.axonframework.springboot.util.jpa.ContainerManagedEntityManagerProvider containerManagedEntityManagerProvider) {
        CommandBus commandBus = SimpleCommandBus.builder().build();
        commandBus.registerDispatchInterceptor(
                new CatalogDispatchInterceptor(containerManagedEntityManagerProvider.getEntityManager()));
        return commandBus;
    }

}


public class CatalogDispatchInterceptor implements MessageDispatchInterceptor<CommandMessage<?>> {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public CatalogDispatchInterceptor(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public BiFunction<Integer, CommandMessage<?>, CommandMessage<?>> handle(
            List<? extends CommandMessage<?>> messages) {
        return (index, command) -> {
             (CreateCatalogCommand.class.isInstance(command.getPayloadType())) { }
            return command;
        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ContainerManagedEntityManagerProvider` instance created by Axon, **if** you are using the  Spring Boot Starter, through the `JpaAutoConfiguration` looks as follows:

```java
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public EntityManagerProvider entityManagerProvider() {
    return new ContainerManagedEntityManagerProvider();
}
```

Hence my first try would be to wire in a `EntityManagerProvider` instead of the `ContainerManagedEntityManagerProvider`. If that doesn't work, then you're dealing with a Spring bean ordering issue, which is somewhat out of the (axon) framework's scope I think. You could always just create the `ContainerManagedEntityManagerProvider` yourself of course, which i am pretty certain of will solve the problem at hand.

Hope either solution helps you out Aymen!

Comment: thnx Steven for your answer, it works :) i have another question, do you have an idea how i can check the type of PayloadType, i used isInstance as indicated in above code, but it's not working. thnx

Comment: This essentially is not an Axon question, so I will be referring you to this StackOverflow issue for that -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541749/how-to-determine-an-objects-class