# Catch a specific object inside an Array of mutiple Objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

I created a class called "Object" and two classes "Item" and "Scenery" that implement the class Object ( every item is an object and every scenery is an object)

During my implementation I created an Array of type Object (let's call it `ObjectArray`)- (that can store both items and sceneries).

In another part of the code I need to catch a specific element from `ObjectArray`, and I need to check if it's an Item.

I found a solution but it's too long ( add every item I add `ObjectArray` to another array of only items and check if the element I want to catch exists in both arrays)

But I guess their might be another better way!?

Comment: Please share the code of your tries, that would easier to understand. And don't call a class `Object` , that one already exists and is the superclass of all ones

Comment: Does [`instanceof`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/instanceof) help?

Comment: @azro it's a lot of code behind this explanation.

Comment: @Kulfy your comment answers my qst. thanks !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine an object's class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541749/how-to-determine-an-objects-class)

Comment: Your job to share a minimal example that is enough to understand the real problem, don't share all code

Comment: One suggestion: If you find yourself needing to determine if the elements in an array are one of two types of objects, you need look at your design.

Answer (score 2):

> I created a class called "Object" and two classes "Item" and "Scenery"
> that implement the class Object ( every item is an object and every
> scenery is an object )

In Java, every object is an instance of `Object`, so you don't need explicitly to make `Item` and `Scenery` subtypes. Also, `Object` it's a class so we use to say `implement` with abstract types like `Interfaces` and `extends` for concrete elements.

To determinate what type is the object, you can use `instanceof`

```
Object[] myObj = {new Item(),new Item(), new Scenary()};

for (Object s : myObj)
     if (s instanceof Item)
        System.out.println(s.getClass() + " It's an item!");
```

Pay attention that `instanceof` return true also with subtypes. So let's assume in future you will extend the `Item` class with another class let's call it `SubItem`. If the array of objects contains some `SubItem` instances, the `instanceof` call on `SubItem` will return true. So if you want to determinate precisely if it's the right class object you need a more restricted check just like `s.getClass() == Item.class`.

```
Object[] myObj = {new Item(), new Scenary(), new SubItem(),new SubItem()};

for (Object s : myObj)
     if (s.getClass() == Item.class)
        System.out.println(s.getClass() + " It's an Item!");
```

In this latest scenario, this check will return true only if `s` is effectively a `Item` and not a `SubItem`.
As the latest point don't use Object, always use abstract class or interfaces to aggregate more types. If you will continue to study you will understand why. So what I'm saying is to create an interface for example `Shop` and let both `Item` `Scenery` and eventually `SubItem` implement it. Take notes that with this method both the 3 types are subtypes of the type `Shop` so a `instanceof` for each `Item` `Scenery` and `SubItem` compared with `Shop` will return true.
Summering: `instanceof` will be useful for runtime checks when you have an abstract type and you can't determinate statically the real nature of an object. (Imagine to assign an instantiated `Item` to it's `Shop` for example `Shop obj = new Item();`. You will notice that this assignment is legit.